# Como crear variables de forma dinámica en C?

Tags: c

Quería saber si habría alguna forma de crear variables de forma dinámicas en C ?

Ejemplo:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
 int 'int_i' = 'valor de i'
}
```

Al final de la ejecución tendría dos variables llamadas int_0, e int_1 con los valores 0 y 1 respectivamente. Por lo que estuve investigando no es posible ya que C detecta las variables en tiempo de compilación.
Cualquier respuesta relaciona se agradece.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Juanjo y bienvenido a SOes. Podes seguir el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y [ask] para realizar preguntas de calidad. Podrías usar un arreglo en vez de crear variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se puede. Cosas como ésa pueden funcionar en lenguajes interpretados (JavaScript, por ejemplo), pero no en compilados.

El "nombre de la variable" es algo que existe para que el programador tenga facilidad para escribir y leer el programa. Pero al compilar, lo que hace el compilador es:

- Asignar una posición a la variable.
- Usar esa posición en todas las referencias a la variable.

Pongamos por caso

```
int miFuncion(int parametro1, int parametro2, int parametro3) {
   int local;
   local = parametro1 + parametro2 + parametro3;
   return local * 2;
}
```

En este caso son todo variables locales, así que tendrán posiciones relativas al *stack pointer*

Una implementación sencilla del compilador<sup>1</sup> haría un código que, al llamar a la función:

1. Guarda en la posición SP (stack pointer) + 0 la dirección donde se debe volver al acabar la ejecución de la función.
2. Reserva en SP + 1 el espacio para el valor devuelto.
3. Reserva SP + 2, SP + 3 y SP + 4 espacio para los parámetros 1, 2 y 3. Al invocar la función, el código que la invoca guardará en esas posiciones los valores de los parámetros.
4. Reserva SP + 5 para `local`.
5. Genera el código que:

   a. suma SP + 2 y SP + 3 y guarda el resultado en SP + 6.

   b. suma SP + 6 y SP + 4 y guarda el resultado en SP + 5.

   c. multiplica SP + 5 por 2 y guarda el resultado en SP + 1 (valor devuelto).

   d. lee SP y pasa la ejecución a esa posición de memoria, saliendo del método.

Sencillamente, en tiempo de ejecución ni se crean variables, ni el nombre está accesible.

La opción obvia, si conoces el número de variables a crear al programar, sería usar un array o un struct. En caso de que no lo conozcas, puedes usar memoria dinámica y punteros (`malloc` y compañía).

---

<sup>1</sup>En realidad cualquier compilador actual optimizaría mucho lo que ves, pero este ejemplo es más visual.

Comment: Eso es desde el punto de vista del programador, las variables pueden o no agregar un símbolo en la tabla de símbolos del objeto, el cual le sirve al enlazador para la re asignación de memoria para generar una imagen ejecutable, si no hay símbolos entonces el enlazador no hará nada, dicha problemática debe manejarla el compilador, si fuese simplemente posiciones en memoria, entonces no habría necesidad de crear variables en primer lugar...

Comment: Gracias ! Buscaba una respuesta concisa como la tuya.